# Find Address of cell from Index match VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The below Code finds the value of a certain cell without any problem. However I am not interested in the value. What I need is the Cell Address. I wish to later in the code use this new found address to adjust it value a few times depending on different factors.

I could use the Address function if this was not in VBA but I have not found a way to use it or anything similar in VBA.

```
Sub IndexMatch()

    A = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Workbooks("AllSwipes.xlsx").Worksheets("Backend").Range("H1:CY1"), 1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SomeGlobalVariable, Workbooks("AllSwipes.xlsx").Worksheets("Backend").Range("H1:CY1"), 0)).Offset(1, 0)

    MsgBox A


End Sub
```

Comment: `A = Workbooks("AllSwipes.xlsx").Worksheets("Backend").Range("H1").Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SomeGlobalVariable, Workbooks("AllSwipes.xlsx").Worksheets("Backend").Range("H1:CY1"), 0))-1,).Address`

Comment: This got me on the right track i just need to add .Address to the end of what I had written which I thought I had already tried but it worked this time. Your code found that the Variable was the in the 9 column so it returned $H$10. But I need $P$2, I was needing the same column and to offset one row down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as adding .Address to my code Thanks @ScottCraner for pointing me in the right direction.